# Which philosopher fits the following description?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

I'm not a philosopher so please forgive me if this question does not belong here

here is a list of my interpretation of other philosophers that I'm familiar with

| Their names | Their words | My interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roger Penrose | knowably sound | mathematical purpose |
| David Chalmers | subjective experience | mental meaning |
| John Searle | chinese room | material joy |
| Daniel Dennett | user illusion | awful hell |
| Kurt Godel | a priori truth | lovely heaven |
| ? | ? | wonderful peace |

which philosopher do you know that you think fit the question mark ?

Comment: This question seems to make no sense as something anyone would actually be wondering about (because you can't have "my interpretation" for a philosopher, when you don't know the philosopher). It just seems like a (somewhat questionable) exercise from a textbook, for which I can only recommend that you read your textbook instead of crowdsourcing the internet for the answer. If you can't find the answer (or make a reasonable guess), then just leave it blank - that'll tell your teacher far more about where your understanding is at compared to an answer copied from the internet.

Comment: @NotThatGuy this is not a textbook question I'm actually wondering about this question, sorry if it does not make any sense, some older people may find it meaningful

Comment: I sure hope Kurt Gödel has found that wonderful peace.

Comment: In partial agreement with @NotThatGuy, and to stave off closure, I suggest  (a) for each 'philosopher' to add a bit more than just a name in a table (b) add some more canonical philosophers eg Kant, Plato, Nietzsche etc

Comment: @Rushi as I said I'm not a philosopher so I don't have anything more to say about them other than their words of wisdom

Answer (score 1):

Eckhart Tolle : The Power of Now

> Realize this: The present moment is all you ever have. Make the Now the primary focus of your life.

As for peace

> Don't look for peace. Don't look for any other state than the one you are in now; otherwise, you will set up inner conflict and unconscious resistance. Forgive yourself for not being at peace. The moment you completely accept your non-peace, your non-peace becomes transmuted into peace. Anything you accept fully will get you there, will take you into peace. This is the miracle of surrender

Comment: Unctuous uttering of mystic sentences does not transmute Eckhart Tolle into a philosopher - śāntiḥ, śāntiḥ, śāntiḥ …